# How can I add a "dynamic" AREA attribute to a polyline using ezdxf?

Tags: python, autocad, polyline, dxf

I am using the *ezdxf* library to generate DXF files with polylines and different attributes which are given within a polyline as text. Using *ezdxf*, how can I create an AREA attribute which would be connected to a polyline? This means, if I open a created DXF file in AutoCAD and change the polyline geometry, then the AREA text would update its value automatically.

Here is how I do it in AutoCAD:

[image: Assigning AREA to POLYLINE OBJECT in AutoCAD]

Here is an example of what kind of behavior I want to achieve in AutoCAD:

1. AREA attribute state when I open the DXF file:

   [image: AREA attribute state when I open the DXF file.]
2. Changing the geometry of the POLYLINE:

   [image: Changing the geometry of the POLYLINE]
3. After I apply the REGEN command, the AREA attribute value gets updated:

   [image: After I apply REGEN command, the AREA attribute value gets updated.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, but you would need to write the definition of the Extension Dictionary attached to the attribute definition, the `ACAD_FIELD` dictionary contained within the Extension Dictionary, the `TEXT` dictionary contained within that, the `FIELD` entity container, and finally, the `FIELD` entity which references the object property itself.

You can inspect the DXF data for each of these dictionaries & entities using a utility such as my [Entity List](http://lee-mac.com/entitylist.html) program, and drill-down through the entries starting with the Extension Dictionary.